# .NET Core DI equivalent to Autofac's WithParameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am using this in Autofac with the following registration:

```cs
builder.RegisterType<SBOTaskerHelper>()
    .As<ISBOTaskerHelper>()
    .AsSelf()
    .UsingConstructor(
        typeof(IPrincipal),
        typeof(IPortalSettings),
        typeof(ILogger<SBOTaskerHelper>),
        typeof(bool))
    .WithParameter("debugMode", Portal.Site.DebugMode)
    .InstancePerRequest();
```

Moving to ASP.NET Core dependency injection. How to pass constructors and parameters to configure services DI?

Comment: The default DI is too simple to do what you want. Autofac however can integrate into asp.net core. You can use the same code shown in asp.net core DI. Check documentation here https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#quick-start

Comment: Thank you for the documentation @Nkosi, it helped me understanding some bits that I didnt know of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following registration would be roughly the same:

```cs
services.AddScoped<SBOTaskerHelper>(
    p => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<SBOTaskerHelper>(
        p, Portal.Site.DebugMode));
services.AddScoped<ISBOTaskerHelper>(
    p => p.GetRequiredService<SBOTaskerHelper>());
```

`ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` is a helper method of MS.DI. It allows creating the given type, where its dependencies are resolved from the supplied `IServiceProvider`, while allowing constructor arguments to be overridden. In this case we're instructing MS.DI to supply the `Portal.Site.DebugMode` to the first `bool` property in `SBOTaskerHelper`'s constructor.

Note that there is no `.As<T>().AsSelf()` in MS.DI. You need to add a second registration and forward the registration to the previous one. This is done using `services.AddXXX<IX>(p => p.GetRequiredService<X>())`.